# Eclipse WindowBuilder in Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, windowbuilder

I am using Eclipse Photon version in Mac.
and I downloaded windowBuilder through 
"Install new software"-> "windowBuilder / http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.8/"....
And i restarted eclipse and eclipse told me......

However after install, I could not find jframe class or Windowbuilder class from command+N (creating new classes.....)

can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Do you mean there's no WindowBuilder folder listed in the Wizards list of New command? Like the feature did not install properly?

Comment: yes!! there in no windowBuilder folder listed in the wizards......I did properly installed WindowBuilder.......

Comment: Could you do this: Window->Show View->Console. Drop down 'Open Console' button and choose Host OSGi Console. Type in the command 'ss wb.' to list bundles of your Eclipse installation. Could you include the displayed result in your question?

Comment: Well....I only have java trace console and maven console......

Comment: Could it be that you're Eclipse IDE is not the one with RCP and RAP package? Which of these are you working with? http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

Comment: mine is Eclipse IDE for Java Developers!!

Answer (score 0):

If the installation worked without errors and Eclipse asked for a restart then the selected features are installed. Most likely you did not select the correct features.

The easiest way to install WindowBuilder is to find it through the Eclipse Marketplace client. This can be found in the "Help" menu.

If you still want to install manually, the correct update sites can be found here:

- https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

You may install all features that are in the WindowBuilder category:

- Swing Designer
- Swing Designer Documentation
- SWT Designer
- SWT Designer Core
- SWT Designer Documentation
- SWT Designer SWT_AWT Support
- WindowBuilder Core
- WindowBuilder Core Documentation
- WindowBuilder Core UI
- WindowBuilder GroupLayout Support
- WindowBuilder Java Core

> **Do not install the XWT support unless you know what you are doing.**

Answer (score 0):

It is worked for me:

https://youtu.be/WXKMjBWSrrc

uninstall old eclipse
use eclipse 2021-06